# Differences between python Queue.Queue and multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyside

My program does not close cleanly when I use the queue from the multiprocessing module (Python 2.7 on Windows) in place of Queue.Queue.

Eventually I want to process the frames in imgbuffer using a multiprocessing.Process and then pull back display data using a second queue. This does not work yet - it seems like Process.start() does nothing - but since I am having trouble making progress debugging the multiprocessing code, I thought I would pare back to the simplest code I have that is broken and see if anyone had ideas on what to try next.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import cv2
import time, datetime
import multiprocessing
import Queue #needed separately for the Empty exception

def imageOpenCv2ToQImage(cv_img):
   height, width, bytesPerComponent = cv_img.shape
   bytesPerLine = bytesPerComponent * width;
   cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2RGB, cv_img)
   return QtGui.QImage(cv_img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)

class VideoWidget(QtGui.QLabel):
   def __init__(self):
      super(VideoWidget, self).__init__()

      self.imgbuffer = multiprocessing.Queue() 
      ############################################
      # hangs on quit using multiprocessing.Queue
      # works fine when I use Queue.Queue
      #########################################

      self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1) # camera ID depends on system: 0, 1, etc

      self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
      self.setScaledContents(True)

      target_FPS = 30.0
      self.camera_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
      self.camera_timer.timeout.connect(self.on_camera_timer)
      self.camera_timer.start(1000.0/target_FPS)

      target_FPS = 40.0
      self.repaint_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
      self.repaint_timer.timeout.connect(self.on_repaint_timer)
      self.repaint_timer.start(1000.0/target_FPS)

   def shutdown(self):
      self.camera.release()

   def on_camera_timer(self):
      hello, cv_img = self.camera.read()
      tstamp = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.imgbuffer.put((tstamp, cv_img))

   def on_repaint_timer(self):
      try:
         tstamp, cv_img = self.imgbuffer.get(False)
         pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(imageOpenCv2ToQImage(cv_img))
         self.setPixmap(pixmap)
      except Queue.Empty:
         pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = VideoWidget()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(widget.shutdown)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... the answer was in the documentation after all:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

In particular:

> They differ in that Queue lacks the task_done() and join() methods
>   introduced into Python 2.5’s queue.Queue class.

In my case, the solution seems to be adding this to the shutdown code:

```
self.imgbuffer.cancel_join_thread()
```